# thread behaviour when not joined and main process killed

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, pthreads

I have a process, it creates a pthread but this thread is not joined to main thread. This thread has an infinite loop. When the process starts this thread also starts, but if the process is killed using SIGKILL, will this thread be killed automatically or will it turn to zombie thread?

Thanks,

Rohit

Answer (score 1):

The `SIGKILL` signal forcefully terminates the entire process, regardless of how many threads it has and what those thread are doing.  This signal cannot be caught or ignored.

If the process's parent is still alive when this happens, the process will be in a zombie state until the parent process calls `wait` or its variants.

Comment: if the process A(pid-1234) starts pthread ptA[ptA runs infinite loop], and we issue sigkill to A(pid-1234), is ptA stopped/killed too?

Comment: @user1254554 Yes, if a process is killed, all threads in that process are killed.  A thread cannot exist without a process.

Answer (score 0):

SIGKILL cannot be ignored/handled by any process.
When the main thread returns, it terminates the entire process. This includes all other threads within the process. The same thing happens when you call exit from any thread.

To Linux, there is no such "explicit" difference between a process and a thread.
Each of them is represented by a `task_struct` in Kernel and they are chained together.

Each Process main thread has a pid and task group id(tgid).So, all the threads also have the same pid or tgid.

When a process is cleaned, all it's `child processes,not threads are reparented`.

It's more about semantics:

A thread shares it's resources with it's parent, which basically means memory mappings,file descriptors etc.

When the process itself does not exist, who are the threads going to share the resources with??

You cannot reparent them to some other process since they would need to acess it's resources.

> So, in short ,  A child process can be reparented since it does not
>   share any resources, where as a child thread cannot be reparented

.

If you want to dig deeper, you can start off here:
[makelinux](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch03lev1sec3)

Comment: "*The same thing happens when you call exit from main thread.*" in fact the process ends when calling `exit()` from *any* thread.

Comment: changed accordingly :)